# Insert statement never works, no matter how many different types I try. Sqlite3 pyscripter

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pyscripter

I have been trying to work out how to insert into a SQL table for days. Nothing I try ever works and I just spent hours fixing all the errors, to find that I am back to the start where the insert statement doesnt insert anything. I only have a couple of hours left and I cant do anything else with my code until this is fixed, thanks.

I dont understand at all what is wrong, and there isnt any errors anymore. It just prints out the table without anything in it. I would like it to print out the inputs which I have (They are defined in the full code and I have checked they do work and print)

```
def insert_user():
    import sqlite3
    score = "0"
    db = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,firstname, surname, age, password , score) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    db.execute(sql,(usernamei, first_name ,last_name , age, passwordi ,score))
    db.commit()
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print()
    print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<20} {3:<20} {4:<20} {5:<20}".format("userID","username","firstname","surname","age","password","score"))
    print("====================================================================================================")
    for each in result:
            print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<20} {3:<20} {4:<20} {5:<20}".format(each[1],each[2],each[3],each[4],each[5],each[6]))


insert_user()
```

Comment: what happens if you `SELECT` the table contents ? `INSERT` is *not* supposed to return any results. Do you have any SQL experience ?

Comment: `cursor.fetchall()` what are you fetching? you didnt query anything

Comment: I will try to select, and no I don't have any, we got taught it the day we started out nea. I dont really know what I am fetching, I will get rid of that statement and see what happens.

Comment: also you should probably not do `db.execute` but do `cursor.execute` instead

Comment: I tried to do SELECT instead of INSERT INTO and I get a syntax error, am I writing it wrong?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM users` and then `cursor.fetchall()` that.

Comment: I have changed the db to cursor.

Comment: this is a great resource to learn SQL - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)

Comment: I think the problem is that it isnt inserting anything into the table. Becayse it seems to print the empty table fine. I have to go but I will checkl again later. Thanks

Comment: you should get some kind of an error if the data is not inserted. You don't have any logic in the sql. Are you sure that these variables have *any* value in them ? `(usernamei, first_name ,last_name , age, passwordi ,score)`

Comment: Yea, I have checked by printing them out . I really dont understand what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE a Cursor is not used. To get data from a table you use (execute) **SELECT** SQL, the cursor will then contain the result set.

So you need to do the INSERTS and then execute a SELECT e.g. using "SELECT * FROM users" and then use `result = cursor.fetchall()`.

instead of executing against the connection you execute against the cursor.

Something like (for testing the table is dropped and created and hard coded values are used (obviously adjust accordingly)):-

```
def insert_user():
    import sqlite3
    score = "0"
    db = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
    sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users"
    db.execute(sql)
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT UNIQUE, firstname TEXT, surname TEXT, age INTEGER, password TEXT, score INTEGER)"
    db.execute(sql)
    result = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,firstname, surname, age, password , score) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    db.execute(sql,("testusername", "testfirstname","testsurname" , 10, "password" ,score))
    db.commit()
    result.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

    print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<20} {3:<20} {4:<20} {5:<20} {6:<20}".format("userID","username","firstname","surname","age","password","score"))
    print("====================================================================================================")
    for each in result:
            print("{0:<20} {1:<20} {2:<20} {3:<20} {4:<20} {5:<20} {6:20}".format(each[0],each[1],each[2],each[3],each[4],each[5],each[6]))
insert_user()
```

Results in :-

```
E:\PYCharmPythonProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/PYCharmPythonProjects/Test001.py
userID               username             firstname            surname              age                  password             score  

====================================================================================================
1                    testusername         testfirstname        testsurname          10                   password                     0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to not be working still. I have now changed it to that but it still doesn't print out anything, now it doesn't even print out [].

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but omg thanks so much. This is the biggest advancement I have had so far. The only problem is that it only prints out the one that I just did, and not the one before it.

Comment: @Tabitha the above is a demo and hence the DROP and CREATE code is just included to add some testing data. The 4 lines that DROP and CREATE the table wouldn't be included for the real function. That code would be elsewhere and then you wouldn't typically DROP the table.

Comment: Ohhhh ok thanks. Sorry I dont really know SQL . I will take them out and it should work

Comment: Thanks so much. Its now working perfectly. I really appreciate your help and I think I would have failed without you! :D